# To what extent MSO = WS1S, when adding relations?

Tags: lo.logic, automata-theory, descriptive-complexity

[This question has been asked on MathOverflow with no luck a month ago.]

Let me first clarify my definitions.  For a word $w \in \Sigma^*$, with $\Sigma =\{a_1,
\ldots, a_n\}$, I define two structures:

$\mathbb{N}(w) = \langle \mathbb{N}, <, Q_{a_1}, \ldots, Q_{a_n} \rangle$,

and the more usual *word model*:

$\mathbb{N}^r(w) = \langle \{0, \ldots, |w|-1\}, <, Q_{a_1}, \ldots, Q_{a_n} \rangle$,

where $Q_{a_i} = \{p \mid w_p = a_i\}$.

Then WS1S is the set of second order formulas with models of the form
$\mathbb{N}(w)$, with order, and for which second order quantification is
limited to finite subsets of the domain.  MSO is the set of second order
formulas with models of the form $\mathbb{N}^r(w)$, with order.

The usual proof that REG = WS1S proves at the same time that MSO = WS1S.  My
question is then, for which first or second order relations can we keep this
to be true?

For instance, if we add a unary predicate $E(X)$ which says that a
(monadic) second order variable contains an even number of objects, we add no
power, as $E(X)$ is expressible as "there exists $X_1$ and
$X_2$ that partition $X$, in such a way that if an element is in
$X_i$ the next one in $X$ is in $X_j$, $i \neq j$, and
the first element of $X$ is in $X_1$ and the last is in
$X_2$."

Now, if we add a predicate $|X| < |Y|$, then WS1S becomes undecidable
(see Klaedtke & Ruess, 10.1.1.7.3029), while MSO stays trivially decidable.

Thank you.

---

**Edit:** As a side question, ... is this question of interest?  I mean, I'm no expert in the field, so I'm not sure this question is relevant.

Comment: We *do* need Latex math support...

Comment: Ain't we just a click away from it?

Comment: also see the greasemonkey hack mentioned here: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3/latex-math-support

Comment: Was there no joy on MO because they couldn't figure it out, or because they found your question uninteresting? (I'm guessing the latter)

Comment: What are your reasons to think this question is uninteresting?  From a practical point of view, it is useful to know when you can restrict yourself to finite models, isn't it?
For the record, I received no comment on MO.

Comment: Your model $\mathbb{N}(w)$ is very unusual : what is the need of considering a finite word on an infinite underlying structure ? If you forget the letter predicates (which do not change the problem a lot), you are in fact comparing MSO on finite linear orders, and WS1S on the order $\omega$. This is strange, because it is more intuitive to compare different logic formalisms on the same structure.